# Importing photos without using the OS X Photos app

Tags: finder, photos, data-transfer, camera

I would like to import my photos off my camera without using the OS X Photos app and locate my photos direct in the Finder so I can store them in folders, edit them in Photoshop etc. (i.e. do whatever I like with my files without getting involved with the Photos app)

This app automatically recognises my camera and offers to import but I can't work out how to import them to a folder or seperate hardrive where I can sort through the files.

Does anyone know how to import to a folder? or even access the individual files in finder if photos has to be used for import?

…or is there a free import software I can use to avoid "photos " completely

(Theres no camera software available for Yosemite from the company that made my camera)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use Image Capture, in the Applications folder - which is the importer 'behind' Photos.app anyway.

You can set it to auto-launch any capable app, including itself [or do nothing] & set exactly where your imports should be saved. You can also dictate whether it should auto-delete from the camera afterwards, or alternatively you can manually delete any selected pictures.

[image]

Comment: many thanks, it Worked! so much less frustrating this way.

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll never look at Photos again. How can Apple distribute such a bad, the worst app for downloading and editing photos and videos. iPhotos was an Ok and and way much better than Photos. I dp notget what Apple's intentions were. Maybe just to annoy the customers.