# Extracting video from iPhone Zhiyun app gimble

Tags: ios, photos

As my username suggests I have an iPhone with 200gb of video on it. 
I’ve been using the photos app on a MacBook Pro and a usb cable to iPhone to get the video off. I’m new to Mac, only just read about `.nosync`, I’m used to Windows and Linux.

I have hours of footage in a directory on iPhone created by the zhiyun app, a gimble app (a bit like filmic pro, or any app that stores video in itself).

The only way of getting it off the iPhone so far has been to 1st copy it to the Apple photos app from zhiyun app, then usb’ ing it to the Mac (import to photos app). 
I just read [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214279/importing-photos-without-using-the-os-x-photos-app?newreg=9fde45412d0449b6aac6ca608518ce91) that the background to photos app on Mac is image capture, will that do mp4?

Can I “explore” the iPhone and just usb copy off the original files without having to make a copy of all the videos ( by having to copy each video to photos app on the phone). I am constantly running out of space, on theMacBook and phone. Both are 250gb. Should I go back to Windows?

Comment: I think I’ve just worked it out.

Comment: I think I’ve just worked it out. I need a new iPad :(

Comment: Have you tried connecting to iTunes and using iTunes File Sharing?(If the app doesn't show up in iTunes File Sharing, try looking for the option in the app first)